# Azure Hybrid Connection Latency

Tags: azure, hybrid

Good Morning

We have built a App Service front end web application in vue.js that connects to a Backend App Service API in .net core 3.1 that uses the Hybrid Connection to communicate with our On-Premise SQL server.  We have not installed the hybrid connection software endpoint on the SQL server but on another server in the same network.

We have noticed that this is 5-10x slower for most queries compared to our exposed hosted API that we are running at present, both the front end and back end are running on the same version of code. We do expect an increase in time taken but not as much as we are seeing.

What would be causing this to slow down and what are we are able to check to see where the issue is.

Thanks in advance